# turn toDataUrl base64 string into image on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I have created a custom product configurator and i am using html2canvas to generate a base64 encoded string of a canvas element.

If you go to: http://faithpointdallas.com/ecom/page/customStole you can see that when you click "add to cart" at the bottom, it uses the html2canvas script to alert a generated base64 encoded string.

My question is: How can i take that base64 encoded string and turn it into a regular image tag. Like `<img src="myconvertedbase64string.PNG" />`

Here is the code that is generating the string:

```
$('#addToCart').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var target = $('.customstole');
html2canvas(target, {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
    alert(data);
    // data is the Base64-encoded image
}
```

});
});

Comment: Exactly like that ... did you even try it? It should work and the result will be `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K....." />`

Comment: Well yes I have the base64 encoded string but I can't get an actual visual image out of it. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing but if you click the add to cart button you'll see that i'm generating the string. I just need help with figuring out how to turn that string into an actual image on the page as a "preview" for the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help - it uses jQuery to post the base64 encoded URL to the server and then saves it to a file with some PHP:

http://www.rgraph.net/docs/integration-with-server-side-scripting.html#image

Also, did you know that you can use the data: url returned by  toDataUrl() directly as the  tag src?

Comment: I didn't know that and I just found a post RIGHT before you answered with how to do that and got it working. lol. long day.

I'm looking into what you posted here now because thats what I need is the image SAVED on the server somewhere so I can recall it later.

Thanks.