# How to capture a portion of screenshot using javascript + php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to take snap of portion of screenshot, suppose I clicked on XCoordinate 100, YCoordinate 100 then it will take a snapshot of Rect(100,100,150,200) whatever is present on web browser. Any idea in any technology most likely PHP, Javascript will be great solution??

Comment: I hope this is not possible in any language, this would be a big vulnerability.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in any browser. Maybe through something like flash/silverlight runtime?

Comment: That is a huge breach of privacy. If you are the author of the website, you can know at any time what any user is viewing and you can capture coordinates and use webkit in CLI mode to print to a PDF. However, I don't know whether you want to do it for *any* website. If yes, you shouldn't be provided with an answer. Those are simply things one mustn't do.

Comment: Would it not be possible with Mozilla Addons (Custom made)??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks means to perform a task which lead to breach of privacy.

Comment: For what purpose are you after? If you're trying to then automatically manipulate/save the snapshot to a server, then I don't think it's possible, at least i hope it's not. If you're just looking for something the user can use client side to screenshot stuff, then look at a screen capture extension/plugin for the browser.

Comment: I am wanting use in my epaper website... after uploading an image to server I want to make some highlight portion in image so if user will drag his mouse on the particular highlight it will show only that image.

Comment: For admin it will only require to upload an image and he can easily take sccrenshot or runtime PNG if he want to show highlight things.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about just capturing a part YOUR SITE (not any site) they are viewing in a browser, not their entire screen you could do it.

You could use html2canvas to create a canvas of the entire page. You could then convert the canvas into a png. You could also capture the coordinates of the click, use ajax to post the png as a base64encoded string and the coordinates. You would then need to use php to crop the photo based off of coordinates and dimensions desired.

There maybe a way to crop the photo in JavaScript, but I personally have never done it so I don't know off the top of my head.

[html2canvas basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149988/html2canvas-basics)

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/